# Solr 4 Adding Shard to existing Cluster

Tags: solr, lucene

**Background:** I just finished reading the [Apache Solr 4 Cookbook](http://www.packtpub.com/apache-solr-4-cookbook/book). In it the author  mentions that setting up shards needs to be done wisely b/c new ones cannot be added to an existing cluster. However, this was written using Solr 4.0 and at the present I am using 4.1. Is this still the case? I wish I hadn't found this [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-3755) and I'm hoping someone can tell me otherwise.

**Question:** Am I expected to know how much data I'll store in the future when setting up shards in a SolrCloud cluster?
I have played with [Solandra](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/cassandra-with-solr-integration-details) and read up on [elastic search](http://www.elasticsearch.org/), but quite honestly I am a fan of Solr as it is (and its large community!). I also like Zookeeper. Am I stuck for now or is there a workaround/patch?

***Edit:*** If Question above is NO, could I build a SolrCloud with a bunch (maybe 100 or more) shards and let them grow (internally) and while I grow my data start peeling them off one by one and put them into larger, faster servers with more resources?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, of course you can. You have to setup a new Solr server pointing to the same zookeeper instance. During the bootstrap the server connects to zk ensemble and registers itself as a cluster member.

Once the registration process is complete, the server is ready to create new cores. You can create replicas of the existing shards using [CoreAdmin](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrCloud#Creating_cores_via_CoreAdmin). Also you can create new shards, but they won't be balanced due to Lucene index format (not all fields are stored), because it may not have all document information to rebalance the cluster, so only new indexed/updated documents will get to this server (**doing this is not recommendable**).

When you setup your SolrCloud you have to create the cluster taking into account your document number growth factor, so if you have 1M documents at first and it grows as 10k docs/day, setup the cluster with 5 shards, so at start you have to host this shards in your two machines initial setup, but in the future, as needed, you can add new servers to the cluster and [move those shards to this new servers](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrCloud#Re-sizing_a_Cluster). Be careful to not overgrow you cluster because, in Lucene, a single 20Gb index split across 5 shards won't be a 4Gb index in every shard. Every shard will take about (single_index_size/num_shards)*1.1 (due to dictionary compression). This may change depending on your term frequency.

The last chance you have is to add the new servers to the cluster and instead of adding new shards/replicas to the existing server, setup a new different collection using your new shards and reindex in parallel to this new collection. Then, once your reindex process finished, swap this collection and the old one.

Comment: Thank you for your time and response, but when you say 'Yes of course you can' it actually sounds like you cant (or shouldnt), no?

Comment: No, you can add servers without issues to host shards(primary) until you reach num_servers == [numShards](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrCloud#Managing_collections_via_the_Collections_API) (collection creation param). Take into account that you can add new replicas for existing shards whenever you need them. The problem only exists when you try to grow over your numShards initial configuration.

Comment: sorry for the delay. YES, that is my question. I dont know how many shards I need at this moment. Maybe 5.. Maybe 5,000. What if I want to index the entire www? How many shards does that require? This is my dilemma. Again- thank you for your time with this.

Comment: "The problem only exists when you try to grow over your numShards initial configuration" >>My Question- I dont know how many shards I need- hence my title: Adding Shards to and Existing Cluster (not replicas - new shards). I dont know how many shards I need. I want to be able to add them and scale with time... and I WANT YOU TO BE RIGHT!! Im just not understanding your answer completely...

Answer (score 3):

One solution to the problem is to use the "implicit router" when creating your Collection.

Lets say - you have to index all "Audit Trail" data of your application into Solr. New Data gets added every day. You might most probably want to shard by year.

You could do something like the below during the initial setup of your collection:

```
admin/collections?
action=CREATE&
name=AuditTrailIndex&
router.name=implicit&
shards=2010,2011,2012,2013,2014&
router.field=year
```

The above command:
a) Creates 5 shards - one each for the current and the last 4 years 2010,2011,2012,2013,2014
b) Routes data to the correct shard based on the value of the "year" field (specified as router.field)

In December 2014, you might add a new shard in preparation for 2015 using the CREATESHARD API (part of the Collections API) - Do something like:

```
/admin/collections?
action=CREATESHARD&
shard=2015&
collection=AuditTrailIndex
```

The above command creates a new shard on the same collection.

When its 2015, all data will get automatically indexed into the "2015" shard assuming your data has the "year" field populated correctly to 2015.

In 2015, if you think you don't need the 2010 shard (based on your data retention requirements) - you could always use the DELETESHARD API to do so:

```
/admin/collections?
action=DELETESHARD&
shard=2015&
collection=AuditTrailIndex
```

P.S.  This solution only works if you used the "implicit router" when creating your collection. Does NOT work when you use the default "compositeId router" - i.e. collections created with the numshards parameter.

This feature is truly a game changer - allows shards to be added dynamically based on growing demands of your business.