# creating shard in SOLR

Tags: java, solr, solrj

I am new to Apache Solr. I have created a new Collection, named [testCollection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyrcM.jpg). This collection has been created through solr admin console and its router type is implicit. I am using the below code to create a new shard to the above collection

```
SolrServer solr = new HttpSolrServer("http://localhost:8983/solr/testCollection");

        UpdateRequest request = new UpdateRequest();
        request.setPath("http://localhost:8983/solr/testCollection");
        request.setMethod(METHOD.GET);
        request.setParam("action", "CREATESHARD");
        request.setParam("collection", "testCollection");
        request.setParam("shard", "latestShard");
        solr.request(request);
        solr.commit();
```

on executing the above I do not get any exception, but no new shard is created. I am using solr 6.1. Although this question might seem a possible duplicate of [Solr 4 - adding shard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14784326/solr-4-adding-shard-to-existing-cluster) but no code snippet is available, also how to achieve this using SolrJ is not mentioned. Any help will be appreciated.

Regards,
Ankur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong api.

The UpdateRequest is for performing actions on the index data (adding/deleting docs etc), not for managing how the collection is set up, for creating a shard for example, you need to use [this](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/6_2_0/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/request/CollectionAdminRequest.CreateShard.html)

Comment: Thank you pointing me in the right direction !. I haven't tried this yet, but I hope the below code will work:
SolrServer solr = new HttpSolrServer("http://localhost:8983/solr");

CollectionAdminResponse response =  CollectionAdminRequest.createShard("testCollection", "test2", solr);

System.out.println("error: "+response.getErrorMessages());
solr.commit();

Answer (score 0):

Create a shard only when the size of collection is grown enough that is too large for a node, so split the collection  adding a shard and finally relocate the shard on a different node.

While possible, I can't think of a situation where do this in Java would be a good idea.

It is way more complicated than just compose the http request and put it into a browser.

`http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/collections?action=CREATESHARD&collection=testCollection&shard=shard2`